# Can't use my Hdd

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, storage

Hi everybody.
Not too long ago i made the switch from windows 10 to ubuntu, and so far it's treating me pretty well, however my hdd is giving me some headaches. my laptop has 128 Gb ssd and a 1 Tb hdd. and as of right now i can only use the ssd. Ubuntu sees my hdd but i am unable to write any information on it. my plan is to use it for large files, and use the ssd for programs i use often. can anybody help me to "fix" my hdd so i can use it? any help will be much appreciated.

If you need any additional info you let me now and i will post it here.
Love from Denmark

Ps. I am not duel bootin'

**output from "sudo fdisk -l"**

```
Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes   
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes   
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disklabel type: gpt   
Disk identifier: 55A827BF-D340-4E23-AFDF-DF3E1EAC2783

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type   
/dev/sda1       2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System   
/dev/sda2    1050624 216795135 215744512 102.9G Linux filesystem  
/dev/sda3  216795136 250068991  33273856  15.9G Linux swap


Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors       
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes   
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes   
Disklabel type: dos  
Disk identifier: 0x70a8317e   

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type  
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953523711 1953521664 931.5G 83 Linux
```

**lsblk -lf output:**

```
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT  
sdb                                                    
sdb1 ext4   Data  74e861c6-ba1b-4c7f-b220-7ce4a4dba879 /media/victor/Data   
sda                                                    
sda2 ext4         558005ea-0e9e-4aa2-8efc-bef1e7983f27 /   
sda3 swap         21953aa2-916f-4b39-8711-f13a11c9d583 [SWAP]  
sda1 vfat         0AAD-9599                            /boot/efi
```

Comment: is your hdd mounted?

Comment: it is also possible that it doesn't have any filesystem on it so far so you would have to format it. Please add the output of `sudo fdisk -l` to your question

Comment: Add this command output to your question: `lsblk -lf`.

Comment: Good chance it's NTFS formatted if you used it under Windows.
`df -T` will show the file system type

Comment: @mjb2kmn this wouldn't madder actually because linux can read ntfs. It's just not working the other way round trying to read ext3/4 from windows

Comment: I have add the additional info in the question now, thank you very much.

Comment: @derHugo right, but the poster said it "sees" it but is unable to write. Linux can (sometimes) read NTFS but not write. It was a shot in the dark before the question edit.

Comment: Victorwp could it be that you formatted the hdd with different user?

Comment: Greg, i think i formatted the drive for at live ubuntu usb. If that could have anything to do with it?

Comment: `sudo chown -R USERNAME:USERNAME /media/victor` replacing USERNAME by your own. Does it allow writing now?

Comment: @CelticWarrior use $USER and there is no need for him to change USERNAME for his own :)

Comment: @Rinzwind You're right. Old habits is what it is. Please use `sudo chown -R $USER /media/victor`

Comment: It works!!! thank you so much guys, much appropriated, love this community.